# Design Pattern to Merge Functionality of Two+ External Libraries

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm using two third party libraries to perform similar functionality. I need to be able to decide which library  to use at runtime (each one is superior at a different kind of task and I only know which one is needed for a specific task at runtime).

I'm trying to create a single class so I could dynamically invoke the functionality of a specific library at run time. Initially, I thought of using the adapter pattern however the issue is that both libraries return different types of objects and the adapter pattern will only be useful if the interface (or signature) is the same.

To provide a specific example, the `Selenium` framework allows me to extract a web element from a page by calling the method `driver.findElement(By.Xpath("XPath"))` on a `WebDriver` instance. Similarly, the `XSoup` framework (an extension of `JSoup`) allows me to perform the same functionality by calling `Xsoup. compile( "XPath" ).evaluate(doc ).getElements();`. The functionality of both methods are semantically equivalent  - however they both return (and expect) two different types of objects (`WebDriver` returns a `WebElement` and `XSoup` returns a instance of `Element` - two different objects. Similarly, `WebDriver` expects a `driver` object and `XSoup` expects a `document` object to be passed in as a parameter).

My goal is to merge the functionality of the two frameworks by calling a single method (such as `getElement()` in this case) and let the method deal with the details of calling the correct library/framework (based on some parameter passed to the method for instance)

What design pattern could be used to merge the functionality of both libraries at run time?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not enough to simply encapsulate the logic into a single method whose signature is a _facade_ for accessing the required functionality? Client code accessing this method would then not need to depend on these two libraries. If you posted the code you have so far and clarified what you think is lacking, it would be easier to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with the adapter pattern.  It sounds like you'll need two levels of it.

You'll first need to define a common interface that is capable of wrapping a WebElement and an Element:

```java
public interface MyElement {
    String getText();
}  

public class SeleniumElement implements MyElement {
    private WebElement element;

    public SeleniumElement(WebElement element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return element.getText();
    }
}

public class XSoupElement implements MyElement {
    private Element element;

    public XSoupElement(Element element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return element.text();
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to define an interface that returns these values and have one implementation for XSoup and whatever other libraries you're using.  The implementations will just wrap the return values from the library:

```java
public interface Driver {
    public MyElement findByXpath(String xpath);
}

public class MySeleniumDriver implements Driver {
    public MyElement findByXpath(String xpath) {
        return new SeleniumElement(driver.findElement(By.Xpath(xpath)));
    }
}

public class MyXSoupDriver implements Driver {
    public MyElement findByXpath(String xpath) {
        return new XSoupElement(Xsoup.compile(xpath).evaluate(doc).getElement());
    }
}
```

Then at runtime you can change the framework you use:

```java
Driver myDriver = isSeliniumBetter ? new MySeliniumDriver() : MyXSoupDriver();

String text = myDriver.findByXPath("xpath").getText();
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I just wanted to return a "unified" element (w/o performing the method 'getText()' ) I don't see how this would help.. unless I missed something.. How are you combining WebElement & Element objects?

Comment: Can you better describe what you mean by "unified"? How would you like to use it in code? The point of MyElement is to in effect unify the two libraries behind a common interface you can use to switch implementations at runtime.  You can't unify two different interfaces like this without providing your own common interface, the type system won't allow it. There may be a slightly better pattern however depending on your use if you give an example.